# Dyndns2 protocol specification?

Tags: dyndns

I’m seeing a “DynDNS2” protocol referenced a lot but
I have a hard time locating its specification. AFAICS,
RFC 2136 is not versioned on the protocol level so I’m
inclined to rule that one out. Somehow I can find
numerous implementations of DynDNS2 but the repos I’ve
browsed don’t link to a canonical document either.

Example: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083
– that’s Google claiming they support this protocol without
further explanation.

Where can I find the official specification of DynDNS2?

Who is in charge of its standardization and development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link (now) shows how to do so "manually":

```
https://username:password@domains.google.com/nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4
```

And gives more specs.
You should check the [link to the support page](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083) again and click the *Using the API to update your Dynamic DNS record*

```
Example HTTP query:
POST /nic/update?hostname=subdomain.yourdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4 HTTP/1.1
Host: domains.google.com
Authorization: Basic base64-encoded-auth-string User-Agent: Chrome/41.0 your_email@yourdomain.com
```

Also you need to add the User Agent header to make sure your call is not ignored or worse, your client is blocked.

At source forge you can find [a list of these dynamic DNS "protocols"](https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/protocols/).

Answer (score 1):

Dyn.com has quite good [documentation on their site](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/) including [flow diagram](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/flow-diagram/), [update api](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/perform-update/) and [return codes](https://help.dyn.com/remote-access-api/return-codes/)

Comment: AFAICS that page doesn’t mention “dyndns2” as a protocol anywhere. This might as well be a description of some private implementation of theirs.

Comment: It is the company which created the protocol, formerly DynDns, a few years ago renamed to Dyn

Answer (score 0):

The [RFC 2136](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2136) spec is an extension of the DNS itself and used by [nsupdate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nsupdate) command. It's complicated  and is used by sysadmins.

Routers are using just a plain HTTP GET requests to some DDNS provider. Their urls are looking the same as original Dyn.com have: `/nic/update?hostname=[DOMAIN]&myip=[IP]`.

See:

- https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/ddns/client
- https://sourceforge.net/p/ddclient/wiki/protocols/